# Probability theory: How to show that expectation indeed countable additivity for non-negative random variables?

Tags: probability-theory

How can I show that the equation

[image]

is true?

I know the monotone convergence theorem plays a role, but I'm not sure how to bring it in. Should the expected values be written as integrals? Also I should show that the sum is finite.

Comment: Alternative: Half of it can be proven by noting for all positive integers $n$ $$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i \geq \sum_{i=1}^nX_i \implies E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i\right]\geq\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i]$$ and taking $n\rightarrow\infty$ to conclude $$E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i\right]\geq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}E[X_i]$$

Answer (score 1):

If you treat expected values as Lebesgue integrals then this result follows from the monotone convergence theorem, applied to $Y_N=\sum_{n=1}^N X_n$, and linearity of Lebesgue integration. The assumption that either sum is finite is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Put $Y_k:= \sum_{n=1}^k X_k$. Then

$$Y_k \nearrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$$

and by monotone convergence theorem (used in the last equality below)

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}(X_n) = \lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^k \mathbb{E}(X_n)=\lim_{k \to \infty}\mathbb{E}\left(Y_k\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n \right) $$